# How to set onClick for input validation?

Tags: java, android

I am facing the problem on the user input does not go through the validation. It will just direct jump to the next screen when I click on the regSignUp2Btn button. It suppose to provide an error message under the TextInputLayout when user does not provide the validate information. Is there any error for my code?
Below are my code.
Java:

```
    public class signUpScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables
    TextInputLayout regEmail, regName, regPassword, regConfirmPassword;
    TextInputEditText emailEt, nameEt, passwordEt, confirmPasswordEt;
    Button regSignUp2Btn, regToSignInBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_screen);

        regEmail = findViewById(R.id.emailAdd);
        regName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        regPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        regConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);
        regSignUp2Btn = findViewById(R.id.goToSignUp2Btn);
        regToSignInBtn = findViewById(R.id.regToSignInBtn);
        emailEt = findViewById(R.id.emailAddET);
        nameEt = findViewById(R.id.nameET);
        passwordEt = findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
        confirmPasswordEt = findViewById(R.id.confirmPasswordET);

        regSignUp2Btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //Get all the values
            String name = regName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
            String email = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
            String password = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(signUpScreen.this, signUpScreen2.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("email", email);
            intent.putExtra("password", password);
            startActivity(intent);

        }); 

        regToSignInBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(signUpScreen.this, signInScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

    } 

    private boolean validateName() {
        String val = regName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regName.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (val.length() > 30) {
            regName.setError("Username too long");
            return false;
        } else {
            regName.setError(null); //remove error
            regName.setErrorEnabled(false); //remove space
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateEmail() {
        String val = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.+[a-z]+";
        String noWhiteSpace = "\\A\\w{1,30}\\z";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regEmail.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(emailPattern)) {
            regEmail.setError("Invalid email address");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(noWhiteSpace)) {
            regEmail.setError("White spaces are not allowed");
            return false;
        } else {
            regEmail.setError(null);
            regEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validatePassword() {
        String val = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String passwordVal = "^" +
                "(?=.*[0-9])" +         //at least 1 digit
                "(?=.*[a-z])" +         //at least 1 lower case letter
                "(?=.*[A-Z])" +         //at least 1 upper case letter
                "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +      //any letter
                "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" +    //at least 1 special character
                "(?=\\S+$)" +           //no white spaces
                ".{4,}" +               //at least 4 characters
                "$";

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regPassword.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.matches(passwordVal)) {
            regPassword.setError("Password is too weak. Should have 1 symbol, 1 digit, 1 lower case, 1 upper case and at least 4 characters");
            return false;
        } else {
            regPassword.setError(null);
            regPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateConfirmPassword() {
        String val = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String val1 = regConfirmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            regConfirmPassword.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!val.equals(val1)) {
            regPassword.setError(null);
            regConfirmPassword.setError(null);
            regPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
            regConfirmPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
            regConfirmPassword.setError("Password is not same");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void call2ndSignUpScreen(View view) {
        if (!validateEmail() | !validateName() | !validatePassword() | !validateConfirmPassword()) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".signUpScreen"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/signup_back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
            app:tint="@color/black"
            android:contentDescription="@string/backbtn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="227dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/crop" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/create_your_account"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailAdd"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email_address"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:endIconTint="@color/black"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_mail_outline_24"
                app:startIconTint="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailAddET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/name"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/full_name_as_per_ic"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="30"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:endIconTint="@color/black"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_outline_24"
                app:startIconTint="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/password"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:endIconTint="@color/black"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_outline_lock_24"
                app:startIconTint="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:endIconTint="@color/black"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_outline_lock_24"
                app:startIconTint="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToSignUp2Btn"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:background="@color/actionBarColor"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="call2ndSignUpScreen"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regToSignInBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/already_have_an_account_sign_in_now"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this question doesn't seem to involve android studio at all, rather you're asking about android itself. if you're asking about a feature of the IDE, you can use the `android-studio` tag, otherwise just using `android` is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using the `OnClickListener`

```
regSignUp2Btn.setOnClickListener{ 
       /* ....*/
       Intent intent = new Intent(signUpScreen.this, signUpScreen2.class);
       //...
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

This listener doesn't provide a validation and overrides the `android:onClick="call2ndSignUpScreen"` used in the layout.

Change to:

```
regSignUp2Btn.setOnClickListener{ 

      if (!validateEmail() | !validateName() | !validatePassword() | !validateConfirmPassword()) {
            //setError
            return;
      }
      //....your code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in android a button can have only one onClick listener.

In the XML-layout you set the onClick handler on regSignUp2Btn (aka goToSignUp2Btn)

```
    android:onClick="call2ndSignUpScreen"
```

But later, in signUpScreen.onCreate() you try to assigned a second one. However this replaces the onClick handler assigned the XML-layout with one that starts an Activity without validation:

```
    regSignUp2Btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //Get all the values
        ...
        startActivity(intent);
    });
```

You have to combine the validation and the start of the Activity in one OnClickListener.
Delete "android:onClick="call2ndSignUpScreen" from the XML layout.
Delete the method call2ndSignUpScreen(View view) from the Activity. Then, in the Activity's onCreate() method, change the implementation of the OnClickListener of regSignUp2Btn to the following:

```
    regSignUp2Btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!validateEmail() | !validateName() | !validatePassword() | !validateConfirmPassword()) 
             return;
        
        //Get all the values
        String name = regName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String email = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String password = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(signUpScreen.this, signUpScreen2.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        intent.putExtra("email", email);
        intent.putExtra("password", password);
        startActivity(intent);

    });
```